# Can I use javascript to add or remove attributes from a Video tag?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, video, divi-theme

I don't know JavaScript and I want to add some attributes to a video tag.
Is it possible to use JS code that can affect all the videos on one page?

Please see the below code I tried this after some online search not sure if it is correct or not!

I appreciate your help.

```
function playVideo() {
    var elementVar = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
    elementVar.setAttribute("autoplay: autoplay" || "loop: loop" || "controls: false") ;
}
```

Comment: set attribute one by one.
`elementVar.setAttribute("controls", "true");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely set attributes on an element with Javascript. However, the `setAttribute` function needs to be used differently. It takes two arguments:

- The name of the attribute
- The value for that attribute

So in your case this would be a correct way to set the `autoplay` attribute:

```
elementVar.setAttribute("autoplay","autoplay")
```

Also, I'm not sure what does the `or` operator (`||`) is supposed to be doing between the strings. But it looks like you want to set all of those attributes. That needs to be done with 3 calls, like this:

```
elementVar.setAttribute("autoplay","autoplay")
elementVar.setAttribute("loop","loop")
elementVar.setAttribute("controls","false")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use javascript to add attributes to a video tag, but you aren't using the proper syntax.

The [proper syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) for setAttribute is:

```
.setAttribute(attrName, attrValue);
```

Note that it can also only set one attribute at a time, so you can't do `"autoplay: autoplay" || "loop: loop"`.

Here's the code you probably want:

```js
function playVideo() {
    var elementVar = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
    elementVar.setAttribute("autoplay", "autoplay");
    elementVar.setAttribute("loop", "loop");
    elementVar.setAttribute("controls", "false");
}
```